# Lost changes after git rebase before pushing changes

Tags: git, github, rebase, git-rebase

I have commited my code changes to my feature branch but forgot to push the changes. After commit I rebase it with master. Now I can't see my changes. Is there a way to get back the changes from my commit.

Comment: You can use `git reflog` to show a list of previous commits you were at, including your previous branch commit, and then `git checkout SHA` to check out one of those commits. It is strange though that you don't see your changes after the rebase, but you might want to retry the rebase to see if you did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
git reflog
```

Will show you the history where HEAD pointed to just create a new branch on your commit.

Answer (score 0):

If the last commit before rebase is  129e6d3 for example do :

```
git reflog testBranch
git checkout testBranch
git reset —hard 129e6d3
```